# Hashmap len() not updated when element removed?

Tags: rust

I am somewhat tight on memory therefore I want to prevent a Hashmap I am using from reallocating space.

I have:

```
const MAX_HAHSCAP: usize = 16 * 1024 * 1024;

let mut posHash: HashMap<usize, Vec<CPos>> = HashMap::with_capacity(MAX_HASHCAP);
```

and later on I try to make sure that the HashMap never overflows. However, I keep having the condition that `posHash.len() >= posHash.capacity()`. Hence I inserted some code to see what is going on:

```
assert!(posHash.contains_key(&i));
// make sure to remove the entry such that at least 1 slot remains free
if posHash.len() >= posHash.capacity() {
    match posHash.remove(&i) {
       Some(_) => assert!(posHash.len() < posHash.capacity()),   // <-- this is violated
       None => {
          panic!("position #{} was not in the hash?", i);
       }
   };
}
```

Sure enough, the assertion gets violated. (Interestingly, from logging output I know that the capacity() at this point is reported as 27487399, much more than the required 16777216.)
What I am doing wrong here?

Is it possible that the len() function is inaccurate? Is this a bug, maybe?

EDIT: self contained minimal example

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub const MAX_HASHCAP: usize = 16 * 1024 * 1024;

pub fn main() {
    let mut hash: HashMap<usize, Vec<usize>> = HashMap::with_capacity(MAX_HASHCAP);

    println!("hash.len={} hash.capacity={}", hash.len(), hash.capacity());

    for u in 0usize..30_000_000 {
        assert!(hash.len() < hash.capacity());
        let v = hash.entry(u).or_insert((u..u + 3).collect::<Vec<_>>());
        // let sum = v.iter().fold(0, |acc, n| acc + n);
        // v[1] = 42;
        assert!(hash.contains_key(&u));
        if hash.len() >= hash.capacity() {
            println!(
                "before remove: hash.len={} hash.capacity={}",
                hash.len(),
                hash.capacity()
            );
            hash.remove(&u);
            println!(
                "after remove: hash.len={} hash.capacity={}",
                hash.len(),
                hash.capacity()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

When run, the output will be:

```
hash.len=0 hash.capacity=29360128
before remove: hash.len=29360128 hash.capacity=29360128
after remove: hash.len=29360127 hash.capacity=29360127
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: hash.len() < hash.capacity()', src/main.rs:11:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

So the answer seems to be that it **also** reduces the capacity when removing the element that makes the hash full. This is remarkable, but as the docs say

> This number is a lower bound; the HashMap<K, V> might be able to hold
> more, but is guaranteed to be able to hold at least this many.

it is probably okay. I was just not aware of the possibility that the capacity can go down anytime.

Comment: That is weird for sure. Is any `unsafe` code at play here? Would you be able to reduce the code to an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @justinas I will, just wanted to make sure it's not a known bug,

Comment: Output shows that the capacity is reduced on `remove`, along with the length. But if we add more logging, we see that on next insert it will grow - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4ec32661e79ac907e8c545a232b16d17 (I've reduced the size, so that the code isn't killed with timeout).

Comment: @Cerberus Cool site! I didn't know it, but will add to favorites immediately. This behaviour of the hash map is exactly what I tried to avoid. It's unfortunate when you know that allocating more is sure to kill your program.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the hash map may report a smaller capacity once the "marginal" element is removed. Because the docs say that `capacity()` reports a lower bound, it is simply not the case that `h.len() < h.capacity()` must hold after removing an element.